# How to add,update and fetch all event lists from google calendar using php google calendar client Oauth2 API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google\Service\Exception' with
> message '{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing
> required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token,
> login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See
> [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
> "errors": [ { "message": "Login Required.", "domain": "global",
> "reason": "required", "location": "Authorization", "locationType":
> "header" } ], "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "details": [ { "@type":
> "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo", "reason":
> "CREDENTIALS_MISSING", "domain": "googleapis.com", "metadata": {
> "service": "calendar-json.googleapis.com", "method":
> "calendar.v3.Events.Insert" } } ] } } ' in
> /var/www/html/application/third_party/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:128
> Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/application/third_party/v in
> /var/www/html/application/third_party/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php
> on line 128

My code:

```
function getLits(){

    require_once APPPATH .'libraries/glapi/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client =   new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(FCPATH.'xxx.json'); 
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
    $client->addScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
          
          
    $calendarId = 'xxx.google.com';
    $optParams = array(
      'orderBy' => 'startTime',
      'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    );
    
    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId,$optParams);
    
    while(true) {
      foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        echo $event->getSummary();
      }
     echo 'ptoken'; $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
      if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $events = $service->events->listEvents('cwsinfotech.com_6g5d9c73579imk2uvc3guj1ecg@group.calendar.google.com', array('singleEvents' => 'true'));
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    print_r($event);

}
```

I need your help for successfully implementing calendar events API.
Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: did you check the link of the error message? *Request is missing required authentication credential...*

Comment: Hi Vickel, Yes I have followed the link but not get any right solution yet.